# Turn off unused code warning for public functions in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, visibility, inspection

Eclipse was smart about this; IntelliJ not yet. Of course if a function is unused (and untested, I guess I should feel bad for that - even if it's just returning a simple variable, or implementing someone else's interface) but public, it may be used elsewhere. Looking under Inspections and searching for "unused," I don't see visibility settings. Does this granularity exist?

Answer (score 3):

> If you want to highlight unused public methods, please enable the "Settings|Inspections|Declaration redundancy|Unused declaration" global inspection.
>
> If you want to highlight unused private methods, please enable the "Settings|Inspections|Declaration redundancy|Unused symbol" local inspection.
>
> So, if you want to highlight unused private members, but do not highlight unused public members, turn off "Unused declaration" and turn on "Unused symbol".

[Source](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/04/global-unused-declaration-inspection/)

I've just tested it using IDEA 13.1.4, and it worked exactly as described.

Comment: Groan! This setting is gone in IDEA 14.1 (probably disappeared in 14.0). Any suggestions of where to look in 14.1?

Comment: This setting is gone and the suggested solution seems to turn off the private methods as well. Anybody knows a better way to deal with this issue?

Comment: There's a problem report filed and we should vote for it so JetBrains fixes this - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148321

Comment: @trustin: That bug report is now flagged as fixed in version 2016.3.

Comment: this options aren't available for Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

## ... for Kotlin

as of IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (and probably earlier versions), the corresponding setting is:

> File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Inspections | Kotlin | Redundant constructs | Unused symbol

documentation:

> This inspection reports classes, functions or properties in the specified inspection scope that are not used or not reachable from entry points.

There is no setting for *Unused declaration* anymore, so this setting is not for `private` and `public` symbols alike.

### Alternative

Instead of completely turning off warnings about unused symbols, you could use an annotation (possibly defined by yourself), for example `@PublicApi`, to mark all function sand classes that you do not want to get warnings for. You then have to add this annotation as an entry point under:

> File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Inspections | Kotlin | Redundant constructs | Unused symbol | Options | Annotations...

You may have to restart the IDE after that.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off this inspection: File -> Settings -> Inspections(under Project Settings) -> **Unused declaration**(under Declaration redundancy group)， move the hook before it.

[image]

Comment: That turns it off for private as well, no?

Comment: It will turn off inspection for private method. I don't know how to fix it so far.